# What is JSS and how do I get started with building a JSS app?

Tags: jss

I'm not 100% sure what JSS is and I want to experiment with some sample JSS apps and build a JSS app of my own.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**What is JSS?**

- JSS is an SDK - allows developers to build websites using JS frameworks (React, Angular, React Native & Vue)
- Sitecore is used as a Headless CMS - to provide the Sitecore item’s presentation details as JSON.
- It has Full support for the Sitecore Experience Platform - Experience Editor, Personalization, MV testing & Tracking / Analytics (via server-side rendering).
- Apps can be built entirely disconnected from Sitecore - then deployed to Sitecore later (Sitecore install not required)
- You can build your apps Code-first or Sitecore first depending on your requirements and experience.

**Architecture**

[image]

**Integration & Data Flow**

[image]

**Release Process**

- It is developed by Team X at Sitecore outside of the usual Sitecore
  release schedules.
- JSS Is currently in Tech Preview (v9)
- JSS Version 10 will be released with Sitecore with the release of Sitecore 9.1 and this will be the General Release so will be officially supported by Sitecore.

**Pre-requisites**

Ensure you have the following pre-requisites installed:

- Sitecore 9.x (with a Consumption based licence with JSS included)
- Node JS version 6.9 or above
- NPM version 5.7 or above or yarn

**Installing JSS**

- Download and install two jss server packages in sitecore:

  1) JSS Server Package https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/AEB22B31C5F84BA2902B12E897F1316E.ashx

  2) Infrastructure Package
  https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/E23F0D52EB1544228D89E57A6D7E0233.ashx
  (optional but needed to deploy your App to Sitecore)

  More info here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/90_Tech_Preview/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_90_Tech_Preview_3.aspx
- Apply this to the web.config at the bottom of the system.webServer/handlers section:

  *`<add verb="*" path="sitecorejss_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media" name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler" />`*
- Apply this to the web.config inside the system.webServer/modules section:

  *`<add name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Ship.ShipFilter" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Ship.ShipFilter, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Ship" />`*
- Add an API Key in the Core Database here :/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys
- Verify everything is working ok by going to: http://sitecore-host/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}

There is more info on this here:
https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/jss-server-install?id=jss-server-install

**Running A Sample JSS App**

This example is for the React Example App.

1. Add a new binding for ‘JssBasicAppReactWeb’ under sitecore in iis & your hosts file
2. Using command prompt run:

   *`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`*
3. Choose a jss application template (we will use basic-sample-react)
4. Using command prompt run:

   *`jss create my-first-jss-app basic-sample-react
   jss start`*
5. Test the static site on: http://localhost:3001
6. Using command prompt run:

   *`jss setup`*  - then follow setup steps

   *`jss deploy config
   Jss deploy package`*
7. Test the connected site on: http://JssBasicAppReactWeb

There is more info on this here: https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/quick-start-dev

**Sample Template Apps**

The sample apps can be found on Github here:
https://github.com/Sitecore/jss

**More Resources**

- https://jss.sitecore.net - the official docs
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qC5q0Z2GLAk&t=529s - a video of me talking about what JSS is, how it works and a demo of the install process etc (from the Sitecore Sessions organised by Woodrow Mercer)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW57a02oHZ0 - a video I created
  taking you through the install process
- http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/getting-started-sitecore-jss/ - a
  blog post I wrote on Jss. The commands are for Tech Preview 1 so see
  above for the new commands for TP4. I will write a follow up for this
  soon.

Comment: nice!!! 

Comment: One thing to note is you need an active subscription Sitecore license for JSS. Our client is unable to use it with a perpetual license.